# Select maximum value for each row and its column index

Tags: mysql, sql

I am curious if / how a query could be written that returns the maximum value of each row in a table and the index of the column containing that row.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
id INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
field1 INT NOT NULL,
field2 INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2) VALUES
(5, 3),
(65, 89),
(4, 4)
```

The desired result set of the query would be

```
id  max_val col_idx
--  ------- -------
1   5       2
2   89      3
3   4       2
```

(I'd prefer ties in value to return the smallest column index)

Comment: Generally, the answer to this problem is "normalise"

Comment: @Strawberry: Can you elaborate on your comment that the general answer is to 'normalise'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT id , GREATEST(field1, field2) max_val ,
CASE WHEN field1 >= field2  THEN 2 ELSE 3 END col_idx
FROM my_table
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9752a/2)

Comment: Use `>=` instead of two comparisons with `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

this returns the max value at each row.. see working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9752a/9)

```
SELECT
  IF (field1 >= field2, field1, field2) AS max_val,
  IF (field1 >= field2, 2, 3) AS my_index
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

A normalised design might look like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id INT unsigned 
,type INT NOT NULL
,val INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (id,type)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,5),
(1,2,3),
(2,1,65),
(2,2,89),
(3,1,4),
(3,2,4);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+-----+
| id | type | val |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 |    1 |   5 |
|  1 |    2 |   3 |
|  2 |    1 |  65 |
|  2 |    2 |  89 |
|  3 |    1 |   4 |
|  3 |    2 |   4 |
+----+------+-----+
```

And hence...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND (y.val > x.val OR (y.val = x.val AND y.type < x.type)) 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
+----+------+-----+
| id | type | val |
+----+------+-----+
|  1 |    1 |   5 |
|  2 |    2 |  89 |
|  3 |    1 |   4 |
+----+------+-----+
```

...or a more modern, faster alternative.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not the DBA for the database that I'm working with, but if I have future input to how the table relations are structured, I'll make sure they're normalized.